# Has anyone seen this compile error with stripe_payments on iOS flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am running a flutter app on iOS with stripe_payment ^0.1.0.
The demo run with only stripe_payment package builds and runs fine.
It doesn't compile when I have multiple packages in my pubspec.

Tried clearing the pub cache and run flutter packages get, tried deleting pod file and run pod install again

**Error:**

> /Users/../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stripe_payment-0.1.0/ios/Classes/STPAddSourceViewController.m:42:32: error: property 'managedAccountCurrency' not found on object of type 'STPAddSourceViewController *' cardParams.currency = self.managedAccountCurrency; ^ 6 warnings and 1 error generated. Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone Xs. Exited (sigterm)

My pubspec has the following dependencies:

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
flutter_local_notifications:

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9
google_sign_in: ^4.0.6
firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2
url_launcher: ^5.0.1
flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.3.1
geolocator: ^5.1.1
stripe_payment: ^0.1.0
cloud_functions: ^0.4.1
```

Does anyone know where this error is coming from?
I think it a conflict with one of the other packages, but not sure how to find that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated the plugin to support the latest Stripe plugins on Android and iOS, which should have fixed your issue:
https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment/versions/0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my Podfile with:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

And after `flutter clean` I can compile my project.